# Скрыть элемент когда он выходит за родителя ES6

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой код и все устраивает кроме того, что когда мы находимся в родителе и попадаем на элемент то он начинает моргать, так как указан display: none. Перепробывал через contains, но не вышло.

```js
let sp = document.querySelector('.ps'),
  hz = document.querySelector('.zh'),
  x,
  y;

function go() {

  function offset(el) {
    let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
      scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset - document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
      scrollTop = window.pageYOffset - document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    return rect.top + scrollTop;
  }

  hz.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    x = event.clientX;
    let y = event.clientY;
    sp.style.display = 'block';
    sp.style.top = y - offset(hz) + 'px';
    sp.style.left = x  + 'px';

  });

  hz.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    sp.style.display = 'none';

  });
}

go();
```

```css
.zh {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.ps {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Нажми меня</button>
</div>
<button>Нажми меня</button>
<button>Нажми меня</button>



<div class="tab-nav">1</div>
<div class="tab-nav">2</div>
<div class="tab-nav">3</div>

<div class="tab-content">1</div>
<div class="tab-content">2</div>
<div class="tab-content">3</div>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com">youtube.com</a>

<div class="zh">
  <div class="ps">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в каком родителе и на какой элемент?

Comment: Родитель .zh, элемент .ps.

Comment: так а что не так? наводишь на красный квадратик - появляется синий. Что моргать должно я так и не понял

Comment: На полном экране, он моргает когда находится в красном элементе и сейчас заметил, что функция offset работает неправильно, если элемент надохится на странице с прокруткой...

Comment: Сейчас поправил, когда быстро дергаешь мышь то курсор попадает на дочерний блок и он скрывается на мили секунды и появляется. Немного не приятно.

Comment: У меня всё нормально...